# Why doesn't "mycommand >>file1 >>file2" append to both files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, io-redirection

Why does entering:

```
    date >> log >> file
```

into BASH only append the date to file and doesn't affect log?

Comment: It's worth noting that this isn't a bash limitation as such -- "stdout" is an operating-system level construct, a file descriptor that's pre-opened by convention. The rule that a file descriptor can only refer to one file thus isn't part of bash, but is part of operating system design. (That one file can be a FIFO with a program like `tee` on the other end, splitting out each `read` into multiple `writes`, but from the perspective of the program on the left end of the pipeline, its stdout is still just one file).

Comment: The only way bash could avoid it would be to be on the other end of such a FIFO itself, and that would have serious side effects -- preventing software from having direct access to whatever it's *really* writing to (and thus from being able to run ioctl's if connected to a TTY, from being able to seek around or detect the filename if writing to a file, and otherwise from being able to access a great deal of useful functionality).

Answer (score 4):

Because there is only one `stdout`. Bash allows you to redirect `stdout` as many times as you like, but each redirect overrides the previous one, and all redirects are configured before the utility is executed.

This is also true of redirecting `stdin`. `cat < a < b` will only print the contents of `b`, for precisely the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Rici's answer, you can append to both files using `tee`:

`date | tee -a log file`